# Execute MVC method from View without redirection

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm writing a web application running in an Active Directory environment using MVC5.

I have an `AdminController` controller, routing to a View where I can add users to the db.

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    // some initializing code 

    public ActionResult AggiungiUtente()
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult AggiungiUtente(AggiungiUtenteViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(viewModel);
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Within this View I want to put a simple textbox with a button where the user can write an employee's ID or name and he's presented a modal form with the list of AD objects found, then I'll take it from there.

As of now I have the code for all the "pieces", especially the AD tree research method that returns a serialized JSON object that is currently a static method within the ViewModel:

```
public static string ElencoPersonaleJSON(string chiave)
{
    List<ADQuery.Elemento> ElencoPersonale = ADQuery.RicercaGenerica(chiave);

    return ElencoPersonale.ToJSON(); //extension method
}
```

but how can I make it work with the rest of the application? How can I call this method, or how can I call it without being redirected to another view?

Thanks,
Davide.

Comment: why don't you prefer ajax jquery for this.

Comment: @AliHassan for AD tree research or for calling the research method? Actually I don’t have preferences over libraries, it could even be standard MVC. What are you suggesting, exactly?

Comment: I think he is saying use javascript to post the data to the server from the view, and in the backend save it off someplace for reuse elsewhere. You could also create a partial that gets the data and use the partial in your other views if you only need it on the front side.